# getter for boolean properties with JAXB

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, jax-ws

I´m trying to expose services using jax-ws but the first surprise i got was that Weblogic does not support inner classes for request/response objects. After get over this situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144118/jaxb-binding-customization), i´m facing another challenge:

Generate `getXXX()` rather than/additionally to the `isXXX()` Method.

I need to generate this methods cause when i start the service i get the message:

```
<WS data binding error>could not find getter for property 'IsXXX' on com.foo.MyClass
```

Tried a customization:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="false" enableJavaNamingConventions="false">
```

without effect. :(

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BooleanGetter XJC plugin for JAXB is available at http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/~raw,r=1.1/jaxb2-commons/www/boolean-getter/index.html

If you are working with JavaSE 6 then it needs to be re-packaged - see http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=319434

Use in ant build like below:

```
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask" classpathref="development.classpath"/>

    <xjc schema="some.xsd" package="com.acme.jaxb" destdir="gen-src">
        <arg value="-Xcollection-setter-injector"/>  
        <arg value="-Xboolean-getter"/>
    </xjc>
```

HTH

Answer (score 7):

This has been fixed or better to say supported in jaxb 2.1.13 ( see [JAXB-131](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-131) for more details). Upgrade your dependencies and configure enableIntrospection xjc option. More details on xjc options can be found on [this link](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1.13/docs/xjc.html). If you're using org.codehause.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.3.1 plugin see [this issue comment](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAXB-37?focusedCommentId=291602&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-291602) for a workaround.

Option: -enableIntrospection

Answer (score 2):

Here is another plugin which resolves the issue:

http://code.google.com/p/nebulent-xjc-booleangetter/wiki/AboutThisProject

It geneates the `getXXX()` addiotionally to the default `isXXX()` , hence, code already using these classes do not break after applying the plugin.