# Is there a way to configure JAXB plugin to append "get" for boolean getter method instead of "is"

Tags: java, jaxb, maven-3, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I was using the below mentioned `JAXB` plugin in my project

```
<groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
```

Which appends "get" for boolean element. But on migrating to new plugin

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.12.3</version>
```

I get "is" to the getter method for `boolean` type elements. But the code expects the old signature. For example

Suppose, we have following elements of type `boolean`.

a) fileCreated.

New Plugin has generated the following method signature under Generated column.I have listed the expected method under Expected column.

```
       Generated                           Expected
  boolean isFileCreated()             boolean getFileCreated()
```

There is some pieces of code which is not maintained by our team so changing calling code is not in our hands. Please suggest if there is a way to configure this plugin so that it generates the getter for `boolean` as we expect it to be.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the JAXB plugin configuration inside pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.12.3</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>kyc</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>

                            <!-- Added for generating getter for boolean element in XSDs with prefix "get"    starts-->
                            <enableIntrospection>true</enableIntrospection>

                            <!-- Added for generating getter for boolean element in XSDs with prefix "get"    ends-->



                                <generatePackage>XXX.XXX.APackage</generatePackage>
                                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/XXX/</schemaDirectory>
                                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/XXX/generateDirectory>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

After making this change, i am still getting "is" appended property name of type boolean.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202124/getter-for-boolean-properties-with-jaxb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `enableIntrospection` option in maven plugin. [See Here](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/xjc-mojo.html#enableIntrospection)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>

        <execution>
            <id>xjc1</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    <arg>-nv</arg>
                    <arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>
                </args>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.xsd</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>

                <enableIntrospection>true</enableIntrospection>

                <debug>true</debug>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

using an element `<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="flag" type="xs:boolean" />`

```
<enableIntrospection>false</enableIntrospection>
```

generated class `public Boolean isFlag() {`

instead

```
<enableIntrospection>true</enableIntrospection>
```

generated class `public Boolean getFlag() {`

Comment: @Developer the documentation says " If true, enables correct generation of Boolean getters/setters to enable Bean Introspection apis. Since 0.9.0" [Link](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Controlling-the-Output)

Comment: I understood. I'm trying to say that using `<enableIntrospection>true</enableIntrospection>` works as you want. I update my answer.

Comment: @Developer I found only a typo issue on following line `<generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/XXX/generateDirectory>` because missing close tag. I tried your configuration and works fine it is generating `get` instead of `is`.