# JAXB Customizations With a Poorly Formed WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jaxb

This is driving me insane. I have a schema embedded within a WSDL that needs customization because WSIMPORT is throwing the following error

```
[ERROR] Complex type and its child element share the same name "DomainsMap".
Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
line 878 of file:/C:/jaxws-ri/bin/ArtesiaWebServices.wsdl
```

1) I have no control over this WSDL as I am building a WSDL first client and I expect it to go over revisions w/o any formal consultation or release to me.
2) It is not acceptable any longer to manually fix this naming collision because I need to include the construction of stubs into an automated build chain.

I must use an external customization file. I just can't seem to figure out how to get the customization to work.

Here is the offending WSDL fragment:

```
<wsdl:definitions>
    <wsdl:types>
       <xs:schema>
        .
        .
        .
       <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="domainsMap">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="domainsMap">
             <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="entry">
                   <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="key" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="tns:domainValueMap"/>
                     </xs:sequence>
                   </xs:complexType>
                 </xs:element>
               </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
```

This would be a great chance for you to flex your JAXB skills. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've been staring at the jaxb documentation for hours and still no luck. I can offer the entire WSDL if need be. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well this morning I came in to work and was able to figure this out. Sometimes just walking away from the problem and coming back with a fresh head is the best way. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxws:bindings
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  wsdlLocation="ArtesiaWebServices.wsdl">

    <enableWrapperStyle>true</enableWrapperStyle>
    <enableAsyncMapping>false</enableAsyncMapping>
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='domainsMap']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='domainsMap']/xs:complexType">
        <!-- This binding will fix the domainsMap inner element called domainsMap. sheesh, who names stuff like that?! -->
        <jaxb:class name="DomainsMapElement"/>
    </jaxws:bindings>
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='domainValueMap']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='domainValueMap']/xs:complexType">
        <!-- This binding will fix the domainValueMap inner element called domainValueMap. sheesh, who names stuff like that?! -->
        <jaxb:class name="DomainValueMapElement"/>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

I use the above external binding file with the wsimport tool in the following command.

Important things about this binding file:

- The namespace for jaxws bindings is used. This is the only way I could get the node selection to work properly
- The node selection has to end with /xs:complexType. If you stop at selecting the the element name the compiler will generate errors.

  wsimport -d generated -keep -b ArtesiaExternalBinding.xml ArtesiaWebServices.wsdl

Options used: 

**-d generated** specifies the output directory (a folder named 'generated' in this case)

**-b ArtesiaExternalBinding.xml** tells the JAXB compiler to use the binding file.

**-keep** keep the stubs (i just use the stubs for inspection)

finally, I found this to be the most helpful tidbit of information:
[java.net documents on jaxws customizations](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2m1/docs/customizations.html#2.9_XML_schema_customization)

This is what lead me to nesting the jaxb customizations within jaxws tags. Thanks for the link **Petru Gardea**

Comment: Far out ... This just doesn't work without the magic `jaxws` tags when using `wsimport` inside maven plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you've tried or not, but I would do the following:
- make use of the -b option in the wsimport command line (doc available [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)). 
- information on binding files can be found [here](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.1/docs/customizations.html#2.9_XML_schema_customization);
- An in depth view with examples on how to customize to avoid name collisions is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html). I am providing an excerpt here - it should fix your problem.

```
<jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="primer.myPo">
         <jxb:javadoc>
   <![CDATA[<body> Package level documentation for generated package primer.myPo.</body>]]>
         </jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
      <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
          <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
      </jxb:nameXmlTransform> 
</jxb:schemaBindings>
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you will follow through the links I've attached in here; the "information on binding files" link, is anchored on this statement: "These JAXB bindings can live inside the schema or as the child of a jaxws:bindings element."